# How to send private messages with Facebook API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, xmpp

I followed this guide to sending private Facebook messages from a rails app: http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/35-how-to-send-private-messages-with-facebook-api

However, I run into an error when trying to authenticate the client.  My code is below.  It works until the client.auth_sasl line, at which point I get an unspecified error.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
sender_uid= "bn.washer.10"
sender_chat_id = "-#{sender_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
receiver_uid= "rich.zer.11"
receiver_chat_id = "-#{receiver_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
message_body = "message body"
message_subject = "message subject"
jabber_message = Jabber::Message.new(receiver_chat_id, message_body)
jabber_message.subject = message_subject
client = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new(sender_chat_id))
client.connect
tok='CAACdUWyUMNIBAFLT7ZB4j6CiqmoZB3kySPrbg9jOdaSFSSdxk06'
id= ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_ID')
secret= ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET')

#this is where the error occurs!
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client, id, tok, secret), nil)
client.send(jabber_message)
client.close
```

Comment: You say "unspecified", but what does the error say, really?

Comment: It works until you actually try to do something. Cool bananas! What's the error?